# If the teacher dies of old age students were kicked out?

Tags: banished

My teacher died of old age and all my students were kicked out. As far as I know, 'uneducated' people can never go back to school.

How can I prevent students from being kicked out?
Can I 'queue' a replacement teacher in such a case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have any available laborers then the job will remain empty until there is one avilable.

If you notice, when someone holding a job dies, there are 2 messages in the log:

```
"So and so the teacher has died"
"What's his name has replaced so and so as a teacher."
```

Unfortunately you are correct that once the students leave the school they become "Uneducated" laborers and will not return to school. This is due to children and students becoming laborers at the ages of 10 and 17-18 respectively. When a child reaches the age of 10 they have to be either a student or a laborer. If there is no available school, or the school is full, the child goes straight to laborer.

To prevent something like this happening you should always have a few laborers available to mitigate deaths. If you're truly short on workers, try pulling a few people out of jobs that aren't being worked currently. Usually I keep 2 people in builder even when I don't have a build job going and I let my Blacksmiths/Tailors/Woodcutters come and go as my supplies bounce against the cap. Some of these jobs are good to remove in order to have available laborers in times of desperation.

Comment: I've seen a student as old as 20 (apparently a slow learner).

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

If your teacher dies for whatever reason, the school house will no longer have a worker and therefore the process of "educating" your children will cease.

The students being kicked out makes no real difference if you assign another teacher - this can either be prompted by the death notice or by having multiple schools with multiple teachers (or indeed, too many teachers assigned to a school, resulting in unemployment).

Comment: This does not seem to fully answer the questions being asked here and more of just confirms what is already in the question. I think you can find an answer in this but this answer should be improved and/or be more explicitly stated on how to go about doing that.